# When solving differential equations using substitution, does it really matter which substitution you choose?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms, homogeneous-equation, bernoulli-polynomials

My test says to make the "appropriate substitution," but one of the differential equations can be solved as a homogenous substitution and a bernoulli's substitution. Both yield different results. Is it ok to use either? This is the equation:

$$t^2\frac{dy}{dt} + y^2 = ty$$

Comment: Please show us your calculation yielding the two different results so we can rule out potential mistakes. Also please use mathjax for the layout.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to use either?

Sure! Unless an exam/instructor asks/forces you to use a specific one.

Perhaps it would be more accurate to speak of making *"**an** appropriate substitution"* rather than *"**the** appropriate substitution"*, since it may not be unique.

In any case: you can always try *any* substitution, but it will only turn out to be useful if it simplifies the equation or at least enables you to further solve the equation.